# C# - using NumericUpDown to set the number of something

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, numericupdown

I have an C# WinForm App and I'm trying to use a NumericUpDown in order that the user to set the number of persons and the code it doesn't work (inserts value 0 into the database)

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDTipAutocar", txtID.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Marca", cmbMarca.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", cmbModel.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NrLocuri", nmrNR.TextAlign);
        int val = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show(val + "Tipul de autocar a fost adaugat cu succes!");
        this.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Also, could anyone provide a code line to set a condition, like not being equal to 0? Thanks

Comment: Typo? Do you *really* want to save `TextAlign`? -> `nmrNR.TextAlign` ?

Comment: Well.. got it `nmrNR.Value`

Comment: use `nmrNR.Value`. `NumericUpDown` has no `Text` property

Answer (score 1):

Use [`NumericUpDown.Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.value(v=vs.110).aspx) to get its current value. `NumericUpDown` has no Text property.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NrLocuri", nmrNR.Value);
```

For not being `0`:

```
if(nmrNR.Value != 0)
{ //your code }
```